# label studio persistent project with docker

Tags: docker, label-studio

I am trying to setup a docker compose file in such a way that when I restart an image of label studio, I don't lose the project that I have created previously. Is there some way of doing this, either by having a volume set to a specific place or having some sort of file that label studio can use on start up to help define projects? This is my current docker compose file:

```
  lab_studio:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: label_studio.Dockerfile
    container_name: label_studio
    image: label_studio
    environment:
      - LABEL_STUDIO_LOCAL_FILES_SERVING_ENABLED=true
      - LABEL_STUDIO_LOCAL_FILES_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - ./data:./data:rw
```

Thanks

Comment: This does not answer your question (notice the -V for volume mount argument)? 
https://labelstud.io/guide/install.html#Install-with-Docker

Comment: @JustLudo Unless i set something up wrong, that just allows me to share images between the computer and the docker image. It doesnt seem to have any project info stored there. I am using docker compose, so I will put up the code I currently have.

Comment: Ah it seems I missed this. You have already found out what I meant previously, so great! I have no knowledge on label studio but most of the times you can overwrite files on your container by using volume mounts like you mention in your answer. Though not always intended (and sometimes even breaking!) it can often be used to do such tricks. Glad you already found this out yourself.

Comment: @JustLudo yeah I should have been more specific in my question about which folder should be in the volume for the persistance, sorry

Comment: No need for apologies here. I'm just glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the path that appears in the first few lines when the server starts up. In the case of the docker image, for the compose I had to add the following line in volumes:

```
 - ./labelstudio:/root/.local/share/label-studio:rw
```